# User defined conversion and template member question

Tags: c++

I'm using the following example from *Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 764-765*.  I'm a bit confused on it's behavior and looking for guidance.

First, why doesn't `Ptr<X> xp2 = py;` compile, when there is a user defined conversion template function?  FYI, I added this to the example.

Second, why does `Ptr<X> xp{py};` invoke the user defined conversion operator, then when I step through in gdb, the copy constructor `Ptr(const Ptr& r)` is not invoked?  Maybe something is being invoked implicitly?

```
template<typename T> class Ptr
{
    T* p;
public:
    Ptr(T* t) : p{t} {}
    Ptr(const Ptr& r) {p = r.p;}
    template<typename T2>
    explicit operator Ptr<T2>();
};

template<class T>
template<class T2>
Ptr<T>::operator Ptr<T2>()
{
    return Ptr<T2>{p};
}

class X {};
class Y : public X {};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Y y;
    Ptr<Y> py{&y};
    Ptr<X> xp{py};
    //Ptr<X> xp2 = py; // no candidate, thought this would work
    Ptr<X> x2{xp};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: The compiler is allowed to implicitly do *one* conversion to make arguments fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, why doesn't `Ptr<X> xp2 = py;` compile, when there is a user defined conversion template function? FYI, I added this to the example.

This requests *implicit* conversion to `Ptr<X>` but there is no implicit conversion operator. The conversion operator is declared `explicit` so it is not a candidate.

> Second, why does `Ptr<X> xp{py};` invoke the user defined conversion operator, then when I step through in gdb, the copy constructor `Ptr(const Ptr& r)` is not invoked?

The compiler is almost certainly eliding the copy. Try compiling with `-fno-elide-constructors` and then see if the copy constructor is invoked.

Note that copy/move elision is codified in C++17 by temporary materialization rules. In this case there isn't a copy/move at all (no such constructor is even required to exist) so if you are compiling in C++17 mode then even `-fno-elide-constructors` will not cause the copy constructor to be invoked.

Comment: Technically, it's not really even elision any more - there's no copy/move there in the first place. The code doesn't say "make a thing then maybe copy it but actually let's skip the copy" - it says "here's the arg list for constructing a thing but don't do it yet (until I need it materialised)". Kind of an academic distinction though.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Right, that's what I was referring to by "elision is guaranteed." Where there would be a copy before C++17, there may not be in C++17.

Comment: Sorry, not sure you quite got my point. I know you know about guaranteed elision; you've written about it in your answer. I'm saying that, _technically_, that feature is not even really "elision". You don't elide things that never existed in the first place. Instead, the committee changed the fundamental meaning of statements like these. That's in contrast with the old fashioned optimisations we used to enjoy: those _were_ [explicitly permitted] elisions taking place on a line that semantically did indeed involve a copy (or move).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Yes, I do understand the point. I'm saying from the perspective of C++14, C++17 has fewer copies/moves due to the temporary materialization changes. It's not elision of a copy that would have happened in C++17, but it's skipping of a copy that would have happened in C++14 with the same code. It's a codified standard of elision that isn't actually called elision because the copy doesn't happen in C++17 anymore (you can't elide something that's not there). It makes sense to use the term elision when talking about C++ as a family of standards.

Comment: You are correct about explicit causing an issue and the elided constructors.  In regards to explicit conversion, I'm trying to understand where the code is explicit.  Is `Ptr(const Ptr& r)` interpreted as `Ptr(const Ptr<X>& r)` and this causes the user defined conversion operator to be invoked where `operator Ptr<X>` is called as a member of `py`?

Comment: @notaorb Yes, using the name of a template without arguments _within the context of that template_ implies the template arguments. Within `Ptr`, saying `Ptr` without template arguments is the same thing as saying `Ptr<T>`. Note that `Ptr<int>` and `Ptr<float>` are distinct types and there is no automatic conversion between them; the explicit conversion operator in this case adds conversion, but -- being an explicit operator -- the conversion must be explicitly requested somehow. Copy-initialization does implicit conversions only.

Comment: @cdhowie You _didn't_ get it, because you said the opposite thing in response. And I didn't say there weren't fewer copies... and I didn't say it didn't make sense to use the term elision.... what....  okay you know what, just never mind mate.

Comment: @cdhowie In regards to the name of the template within the context of the template implies the template arguments.  I'm assuming this `template<typename T2> explicit operator Ptr<T2>();` because it's another template right?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings We are saying the same thing with different words. It's all good.

Comment: @notaorb Yes. In that case it's an operator for converting a `Ptr<T>` to a `Ptr<T2>`. `explicit operator Ptr();` would be an operator converting the type to itself, which would never be called.

Comment: @cdhowie actually I compiled and `operator Ptr<T>() {return Ptr<T>{};}`  and `explicit operator Ptr() {return Ptr{};}` compile without errors when used in place of the existing template member.  Anyway, this is not related to the question, just a side thought.

Comment: @notaorb Yes my comment about it being an error was incorrect (I've changed that). However, I get a compile-time warning that the operator will never be called because it is a conversion to the same type. If the code in your comment _replaces_ the template conversion operator, you can no longer convert between `Ptr` objects with differing type arguments. The purpose of this argument is to allow one object of an instantiation of `Ptr` to be converted to a different instantiation.

Comment: @cdhowie I regards to the explicit conversion and `Ptr(const Ptr<X>& r)` I read at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion that an implicit conversion is "when the expression is used as the argument when calling a function that is declared with T2 as parameter;".  Is this not the case here?  I'm trying to understand what makes `Ptr<X> xp{py};` and explicit conversion.

Comment: @notaorb See the page on [user-defined conversion operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). The `explicit operator` syntax creates an operator that "participates in direct-initialization and explicit conversions only." `Ptr<X> xp{py};` is direct-initialization. Note in particular that _constructors are not functions._

Comment: @cdhowie Ok, direct initialization is probably only allowed with `explicit` because copy initialization allows implicit conversion of the object.  Thanks!